# Installshield: EnumServicesStatus throw exception issue

Tags: exception, prototype, installshield

I'm a newer in installshield, now, I ran into a problem.

Please look at the Windows definition is below:

```c
BOOL WINAPI EnumServicesStatus(
  _In_         SC_HANDLE hSCManager,
  _In_         DWORD dwServiceType,
  _In_         DWORD dwServiceState,
  _Out_opt_    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS lpServices,
  _In_         DWORD cbBufSize,
  _Out_        LPDWORD pcbBytesNeeded,
  _Out_        LPDWORD lpServicesReturned,
  _Inout_opt_  LPDWORD lpResumeHandle
);
```

he prototype in my installshield script is:

```c
prototype BOOL AdvAPI32.EnumServicesStatus(INT,INT,INT,POINTER,INT,POINTER,POINTER,POINTER);
```

function process:

```c
INT mgrHandle;
NUMBER nSize, nRet;
POINTER lpServices;

begin

    nSize = 0;
    nRet = 0;

try          AdvAPI32.EnumServicesStatus(mgrHandle,SERVICE_WIN32,SERVICE_STATE_ALL,lpServices,1024,&nSize,&nRet,NULL);

catch  
    MessageBox (FormatMessage(Err.LastDllError), WARNING);    
endcatch;
```

it throws a exception, the messagebox shows:The operation completed successfully.
I don't know what went wrong? Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: @Glytzhkof: EnumServicesStatus*lisp*?

Comment: haha, I was checking different language coloring schemes to approximate Installscript. I must have pasted that wrong :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem here is likely due to how you prepare and pass the `lpServices` parameter. Per MSDN's entry on [`EnumServicesStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682637.aspx), it's "A pointer to a buffer that contains an array of ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS structures that receive [data]." That is documentation-speak telling you to allocate a block of memory and pass its address. Afterward, if the function succeeds, that block will contain a bunch of data in the format of [`ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS` structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682651.aspx).

From the API's perspective, the crucial part you are missing is the allocation of that buffer. You have told it there are 1024 bytes of allocated memory starting at the value in `lpServices`, but you have not actually allocated any such memory, nor even set `lpServices` to point to a known location. However `EnumServicesStatus` cannot know this, and will blindly do what you told it. Depending on the actual value in question, the exception is quite likely to be caused by writing to the non-existent buffer, and the function doesn't get a chance to return an error code.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I allocate memory for “lpServices”, it works. I have another problem now. I got pointer “lpServices”，and it points to a buffer that contains an array of ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS structures, how can I get the structure elements?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check Stefan Kruger's http://www.installsite.org. Here is a section on Installscript and services: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isp_svc.htm